# Are Child Packages safe in ADA?

Tags: ada, encapsulation

I am very new to ADA language and, during my learning process, I have been seeing a lot of examples which uses this ADA functionality.
It seems to me that it could be useful only for unit testing in order to being able to test the private types and methods of the parent package, but I don't see any advantage for coding in such way, it seems that breaks encapsulation.

Is it a good practice to use them apart from unit testing?

Answer (score 6):

Child packages can be seen as an extension for their parent.

It can be used, for example, to provide functionalities that are not directly linked to your base package.

The typical example is the Input-Output package.

Imagine the following package :

```vhdl
package Temperature is

    type Kelvin_Temp is private;
    type Celsius_Temp is private;
    
    function build (temp : Positive) return Kelvin_Temp;
    function build (temp : Integer) return Celsius_Temp;

    function to_celsius (temp : in Kelvin_Temp) return Celsius_Temp;
    
    function to_kelvin (temp : in Celsius_Temp) return Kelvin_Temp;
    
  private
    type Kelvin_Temp is 0.0 .. 10_000.0;
    type Celsius_Temp is -273.0 .. 10_000.0;
end Temperature;
```

This package provides basic operations directly linked to the types defined.

What if you want to extend it to provide I/O in text format ?
You can decide to put operations inside the *Temperature* package but if you want to add other types of I/O such as database I/O, you will have a lot of functions that are not directly linked to your types inside the same file.

You can define

```vhdl
package Temperature.Text_IO is

    procedure Put(temp : Celsius_Temp);

    procedure Put(temp : Kelvin_Temp);

end Temperature.Text_IO;
```

and

```vhdl
package Temperature.Database_IO is

   procedure insert (Temp : in Celsius_Temp);

   procedure insert (Temp : in Kelvin_Temp);

end Temperature.Database_IO;
```

That's exactly what is done with [IO in the standard library](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Input_Output)

From an encapsulation point of view, your private types will remain private outside of the package hierarchy so you don't break encapsulation.

Comment: Yes, definitely :D

Comment: Changed it to insert which less error-prone as it is not an Ada keyword

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I still have a question concerning OOP too. Let's say you have a private tagged abstract type Parent_T within package Parent. Is it still a good practice to create a child package Parent.Child that inherits too the type Parent_T? For example as `type Child_T is new Parent_T with private;` I have seen something like this and I don't like too much

Comment: Well, that could be another question ;)  Nevertheless, what don't you like in this ? You can do it the way you prefer, child package or not. Personally, I don't use a child package for doing this but you could take a look at this (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Style_Guide/Object-Oriented_Features )

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at this presentation given at FOSDEM 2018, discussing (private) packages and enforcing safety:

https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/ada_safety/

Comment: That video it's very interesting, thank you for sharing it

Answer (score 1):

Child packages exist to allow programming by extension, but as implemented they also provide a way to bypass the information hiding that pkgs are supposed to enforce.

While it can be convenient to design a hierarchy of pkgs sharing some hidden information, programming by extension is generally a poor idea that emphasizes ease of writing over ease of reading, and coding over software engineering. You might be interested in the article "Breaking the Ada Privacy Act", available [here](https://pragmada.x10hosting.com/papers.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I can't read the whole article qithout paying. That's my point of view but I don't know the language sufficiently for constructing a final opinion.

Comment: That link is supposed to provide free access to the paper. I'll have to have words with them. PM me an e-mail address and I'll send you a copy.

Comment: I thought private messaging was supported on here, but it seems I was mistaken. The paper is on its way.